# Facebook login dialog pop up nothing happening on android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, share

I am trying to implement in my android application a facebok-share button. I have followed the official facebook-android documentation, but after the Dialog appears ("... would like to access your public profile and friend list. Cancel/No"), nothing happening. I am getting back to the activity where my button is located.

**This is how I open the dialog:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
   case R.id.btnFacebook:
      Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

         @Override
         public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
         if (session.isOpened()){
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback(){

               @Override
               public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null){
                     Log.e("D", "Success " + user.getName());
                  }
                  else Log.e("D", "NOPE !");
                }
            });
         }
       }
     });
   break;
}
```

**This method should be called after the Login was success:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
```

Also I have added the facebook SDK -build project-, I have created an App on developers.facebook.com -added the sha1 key-.

I don't know what's going on. There are no error messages, no exception.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with the SHA1 hash key, generated by the debug.keytool. Unfortunately I don't know why the debug.keytool was generated a different key hash.

To get the SHA1 key, which you need to provide on developers.facebook.com (settings) AND in the field where are you creating a new App, you can get it with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
    ...
```

Replace "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto" with your package name (not your class). You will get your key.